# How to connect/disconnect user to VPN using Forms authentication in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

When the user logs in, he will connect with my VPN server, and when he logs out, he will disconnect. Is this possible in a ASP.NET MVC web app using C#?

ASP.NET MVC5

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    UsersController uc = new UsersController();
    if (ModelState.IsValid && uc.UserExists(model) && uc.PasswordValid(model))
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
        return View("Dashboard");
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

When a valid user completes login, he/she will connect to my VPN server and use services.